# Jquery element detects value has been emptied on another child view

Tags: jquery

This code exists on a child and is a tab. I need to know if the value is emptied in another child view and then when focus changes to this tab the change is detected and the copy button is hidden. Hope this make sense.

The value is emptied here:

```
$("#NewPrimaryVoicePreview").empty();
```

Then when user changes focus to this tab, the change in the NewPrimaryVoicePreview element is detected and the divCopyTTStoRSS button is hidden.

```
if ( $("#NewPrimaryTTSMessageBox").length > 0 
    && $("#NewPrimaryTTSMessageBox").val().length > 0 ){

    $("#divCopyTTStoRSS").show();
} else {
    $("#divCopyTTStoRSS").hide;
}
```

Comment: sorry i did not understand your question.

Comment: I have a page of mvc partial views which are presented as tabs. They are all children of same DOM and share the above elements values. In one tab/view user can empty a textbox then view another tab/view and the element NewPrimaryTTSMessageBox will still hold the text as it is not refreshed. I am looking to detect the change in the elements value. Sorry, maybe this is an MVC3 question.

Comment: to detect a emptied textbox you can bind `onchange` or `keyup` event on textbox and check weather the value is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#textBoxId').keyup(function () {
     if($(this).val()=='')
     {//do your work}
});
```